# How do I get Zlib to uncompress from S3 stream in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, stream, compression

Ruby `Zlib::GzipReader` should be created passing an IO-like object (must have a read method that behaves same as the `IO#read`).

My problem is that I can't get this IO-like object from `AWS::S3` lib.
As far as I know, the only way of having a stream from it is passing a block to `S3Object#stream`.

I already tried:

```
Zlib::GzipReader.new(AWS::S3::S3Object.stream('file', 'bucket'))
# Wich gaves me error: undefined method `read' for #<AWS::S3::S3Object::Value:0x000000017cbe78>
```

Does anybody know how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution would be to write the downloaded data to a [`StringIO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), then read it back out:

```
require 'stringio'

io = StringIO.new
io.write AWS::S3::S3Object.value('file', 'bucket')
io.rewind

gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(io)
data = gz.read
gz.close

# do something with data ...
```

A more elaborate way would be to start inflating the gzipped data while the stream is still downloading, which can be achieved with an `IO.pipe`. Something along the lines of this:

```
reader, writer = IO.pipe

fork do
  reader.close
  AWS::S3::S3Object.stream('file', 'bucket') do |chunk|
    writer.write chunk
  end
end

writer.close

gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(reader)
while line = gz.gets
  # do something with line ...
end

gz.close
```

You can also use `Thread` instead of `fork`:

```
reader, writer = IO.pipe

thread = Thread.new do
  AWS::S3::S3Object.stream('file', 'bucket') do |chunk|
    writer.write chunk
  end
  writer.close
end

gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(reader)
while line = gz.gets
  # do something with line
end

gz.close
thread.join
```

Comment: Your first solution is exactly what i came up with, but only as a workaround, as it does one thing at a time (first load into memory then read it)

Comment: I didn't try it because I'm using gz.each_line and (correct if I'm wrong) it won't work this way

Comment: You should be able to replace `gz.read(CHUNK_SIZE)` with `gz.gets` in order to read whole lines. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-gets

Comment: It worked, thank you! Is there any reason why it doesn't work with `Thread.new` but only with `fork`?