# Zlib::GzipFile::Error (not in gzip format) while reading gz file from s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, gzip, zlib

Reading a gz file from s3 gives an error `Zlib::GzipFile::Error (not in gzip format)`

I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016548/how-do-i-get-zlib-to-uncompress-from-s3-stream-in-ruby) to read a gzip file.

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(key,secret),region: 'us-west-2')
resp = s3.get_object(bucket:bucket, key:'2020-03-22-3b1c9b8b3d9649eeb908f03b1748edbe-3825PushlogAgg14713318.gz')

io = StringIO.new

io.write resp.body
#<StringIO:0x00007f8986b249b0> 

io.rewind
gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(io)
Zlib::GzipFile::Error (not in gzip format)
```

How can I fix this error? Or is there any other way to read gz file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a GZIP payload in Ruby Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192368/how-to-read-a-gzip-payload-in-ruby-sinatra)

Comment: A file that does not begin with the octets `0x1f` `0x8b` is in fact **not** in gzip format, so the error message appears to be correct.